# .htaccess RewriteCond excluding directories does not work when there is an .htaccess or php.ini in subdirectory

Tags: htaccess

I have WordPress installed in the server root (`public_html`) for one of my clients, and a subdirectory with a script developed by another programmer that they are still using.

The thing is that this subdirectory has a simple `.htaccess` file with password protection, and a `php.ini` with `register_globals = on` (yeah, I know...).
The problem is that if there is one of these files present, or both, the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` condition does not work and redirects to 404 WordPress page.

WordPress `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Subfolder `.htaccess`:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Orden Puerta"
require valid-user
AuthUserFile "/home3/fdm/.htpasswds/public_html/orden2/passwd"
```

Subfolder `php.ini`:

```
register_globals=on
```

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: What is the exact URL you are requesting? Why do you think that it is the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` directive that is not working?

Comment: Hi @Mrwhite, thanks for your answer. I'm trying to access a folder inside public_html called "orden2" so the url is the following (example, not actual domain) www.example.com/orden2. wordpress is installed in the root folder (public_html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `RewriteEngine On` to the top of the subdirectory `.htaccess` file. This will have the effect of completely overriding the mod_rewrite directives in the parent (ie. WordPress) `.htaccess` file, because mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default.

So by enabling the rewrite engine in the subdirectory, the WordPress front-controller will not execute (by default).

**UPDATE:**

> I'm trying to access a folder inside public_html called "orden2" so the url is the following (example, not actual domain) `www.example.com/orden2`

Note that if you don't specify a trailing slash when requesting a physical directory then mod_dir issues an 301 redirect to append the slash. mod_dir then makes an internal subrequest for the DirectoryIndex. If the DirectoryIndex is set to a fixed URL-path eg. `/index.php` instead of a relative path like `index.php` then the WordPress `index.php` in the document root will always be triggered.

You can try setting the DirectoryIndex in the root `.htaccess` file, *before* all the WordPress directives (ie. before `# BEGIN WordPress`). For example:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

---

Another thing you can try (although this should be unnecessary) is to explicitly make an exception for your subdirectory in the WordPress `.htaccess` file. This should also go *before* the existing directives - at the very top of the file. For example:

```
# Explicitly exclude some URL-paths
RewriteRule ^orden2 - [L]
```

Comment: Makes a lot of sense to me, but still not working :(

Comment: I've updated my answer.